# Bookshelf.js accessing multiple tables that are related

Tags: bookshelf.js

I'm dealing with three tables.

Right now I can get the `feed` of a user (`activities` table) and `activityTypes` object (id,type from `activitytypes` table), but I also need to get `related_user` (`users` table) object of a given activity, so I'll know the details of the related_user if the column isn't empty.

users

```
id
email
username
password_hash
```

activitytypes

```
id
type
```

activities

```
id
user_id (foreign key from users, owner of the activity)
status
activitytype_id (foreign key from activitytypes)
related_user (foreign key from users. 
Shows relation with the user_id, if there's any. 
if activitytype_id is 2 or 3, this will be shown as "followed, "commented", etc.)
```

My models

```
var activityType = db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'activitytypes',
  hasTimestamps: false
});

var activity = db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'activities',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  activityTypes: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(activityType);
  }
});

var user = db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  hasTimestamps: true,
    feed: function() {
    return this.hasMany(activity);
  }
});
```

This is my existing query, how can I add related_user object to it?

```
user.where({id : 43}).fetchAll({withRelated : ['feed.activityTypes']}).then(function(data) {
    data = data.toJSON();
    res.send(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I added a new method to `activity`, like below.

```
userRelated : function() {
    return this.belongsTo(user,'related_user');
  }
```

And here's the updated query. I don't know whether it's the right way or not in terms of optimization, but it works.

```
user.where({
    id: 43
  }).fetchAll({
    withRelated: ['feed.userRelated', 'feed.activityTypes']
  }).then(function(data) {
    data = data.toJSON();
    res.send(data);
  });
```

Right now feed, userRelated and activityTypes return without a problem, everything is in `data` in JSON format.